# Force excel file to download in Action Script

Tags: flash, actionscript, httprequest

I have make a post request to some url. Normally when this url is called from some html form, it opens a dialogue box to download excel file. But when I call this url from flash component, nothing happens. I have to force this excel file to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If url works ok,.. are you sure you put [crossdomain.xml](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_04.html) on the server?

Comment: yeah, it's there, do I need to add some other "header" kind of thing in the request?

Comment: As far as I remember, there should be no special headers. Just `fileRef.download(downloadURLRequest, realFilename);`